# SharedArrayBuffer, Github pages and DNS

Tags: cors, github-pages, webassembly, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-embedder-policy

Buon giorno, here is the situation:

- A git repo hosted through Github pages: https://github.com/ossia/score-web ; I configured Github to put it behind the domain https://ossia.io thus at the address https://ossia.io/score-web
- A WASM app which requires SharedArrayBuffer

As you can check, the website https://ossia.io/score-web returns an error:

```
ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined
```

Which from what the inspector of chrome says:

```
SharedArrayBuffers (SABs) can be used to construct high-resolution timers. High-resolution timers simplify Spectre attacks on cross-origin resources.

To mitigate security risks across browsers, SharedArrayBuffers are gated behind cross-origin isolated contexts starting with Chrome 92 (July 2021). 

To continue using SharedArrayBuffers, please ensure that this page opts-into cross-origin isolation by setting Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy and Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy appropriately.

Note that for each iframe, only the first issue is reported for performance reasons.
```

is a CORS issue.

How can I fix this without:

- Having to change the URL
- Having to move off GH pages

?

Comment: The only way to be able to use `SharedArrayBuffer` is to include the response headers `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy require-corp` and `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy same-origin` — and maybe also `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin`. But GH pages doesn’t provide any way for you to set arbitrary response headers. So there is no solution as long as the requirement is to not move it off GH pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it with the following library which apparently reloads the page and injects the missing CORS headers:

https://github.com/gzuidhof/coi-serviceworker

I just added

```html
<script src="coi-serviceworker.min.js"></script>
```

to the index.html served by the Github Pages website and the JS script next to it and it worked.